# Mysql Cluster Sharding/partitioning

Tags: mysql, cluster, sharding

Ok so i have mysql cluster setup but what i need is say table assets to be split among the nodes, not replicated. as the purpose of me setting up the cluster was due to lack of hard drive space so how do i get the cluster to split the table among the nodes?

I have looked at partitioning but did not find any good martial on it. If anyone knows how to go about partitioning the table Could you please help me.

I know about dbshards ect ect so please do not mention them i need a solution using just mysql and no i cant modify the software that will be using the db

Comment: I think you may be in way over your head here.

Answer (score 2):

not possible using standard mysql. you could look at nbd  clustering,  but it's a completely separate product made by mysql and not completely compatible.

what type of clustering are you using?  replication?  that's not clustering.

if the only problem you were running in to is disk space then you don't need more mysql servers,  just more storage.  a possible solution would be to present a bunch of  iscsi storage to your one mysql server and divide it in to a few  smaller equally sized volumes.  then you could use the partitioning features of mysql abd create hash partitions of your larger tables to evenly distribute them over your volumes.